# How to use application host and port on runtime

Tags: go, kubernetes

I’ve two **differen**t apps in k8s that need needs to read data,e.g. `AppA` from `AppB`, both are deployed on the **same cluster**

The `tricky` part here is that I need the both apps will deployed to any cluster and know the host and port to connect, I **don't** want to use hard-coded values.

e.g.

App A reads data from App B

App `B` is web application with rest API
hence app `A` needs to call like http://10.26.131.136:9090/api/app/getconfig

App A know the service path: like `api/app/getconfig` of App `B` but how it can know the the **host and the port** of appB?

I cannot use it hardcoded , this works if I use `type:LoadBalacer` but this is hard-coded host and port, I need somehow to determine it on run-time maybe with serviceName, etc?

Comment: you can call a service based on its name and namespace, e.g. if we have a service called proxy under the namespace dev we can call the host as : `HOST=proxy.dev.svc`

Comment: @julian- ok thanks, should I define it as type `NodePort` and what is the port which I should use? if any...

Comment: that depends on which port your app is listening. Maybe have a look at this: https://blog.learnk8s.io/connect-service-kubernetes-7cb346cf2f64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: The Kube-DNS naming convention is `service.namespace.svc.cluster-domain.tld` and the default cluster domain is `cluster.local`

So you can refer to your app as ..svc as long as the services are in the same cluster. You then need to check the ports on which the apps are listening by issuing:

```
kubectl -n <namespace> get svc
```

note the service identifier and issue:

```
kubectl -n <namespace> get svc <identifier> -o yaml
```

This will list you the service manifest where you can see which port the app is listening on.

Answer (score 1):

Define a Service for your application B. Then you can access it from other pods with the following url: *your-service-name*:*port*/api/app/getconfig

Comment: sorry I didint get it, how does it know to which IP it should access ?

Comment: @NinaS Take a look at the concept of selectors https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/

Comment: @MartinPaucot - thanks, I already look into it but not found how from restApi I can call to service inside the same cluster... how to define the service etc, if you have example for this it will be great

Comment: Sorry, wrong formatting. I have editted out how should it look. The IP should not matter, as it will load balance between various pods that make up the App B

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2 apps on the same cluster then they can reference eachother via kubernetes' built in DNS.

If AppA needs to reference AppB, then as long as you have a Service defined for AppB, you can reference it with `<service>.<namespace>`. In your case, if AppB was running the in the default namespace you could call `AppB.default/api/app/getconfig`.

The port part can be managed by your service definition. Below I'm using port 80 so I don't have to manually specify the port in my requests

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: AppB
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "80"
    port: 80
    targetPort: 9090
  selector:
    select: AppB
```

More information: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/

Comment: Thanks will try it and let you know :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it so tolerant (from any cluster to any cluster), then you need a DNS, with an external IP address in front of the `App B`.

I would consider hardcoding somewhere. With hardcoding it in one `ConfigMap`, you could get some beautiful implementations.

Comment: Thanks but I cannot hard-coded it :( does with `NodePort` service it will work on the same cluster ? from diffrent cluster this is not a requirement ritght now ... thanks

Comment: In the same cluster, you have no problem. As everyone here is suggesting, you can reach the service (clusterIp would be enough) with `service_name.svc_namespace.svc.cluster.local`, so you can hit this endpoint with your path with no problem always. From different clusters though, you need service discovery.

Answer (score 1):

Create a ClusterIP service for appB.
**hardcode the port**, this port is only for that specific service, and will not have any conflict in different clusters.
do `kubectl get svc <your service>` to get the ip of the service, then use `nslookup <ip>` you can see an fqdn in the result.
Normally, the fqdn is `<your-service>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local`
Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/